# How to take an image of software on debian minimial install

Tags: debian, images, packages

I've finally gotten my laptop to a point where I'm happy with it, I'm somewhat new to linux, so it took me a while to get here.

Is there a way to take an image of the software that is currently installed, so if I reformat I can get back to the same spot more quickly?

If not an image, can I get a list of all the packages that are installed and the configuration settings?  How do you guys reformat your machines to get them back to the way you like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way I know how to do this is [remastersys](http://www.remastersys.com/), though there's certain things to be aware of when doing so. The nice thing with debian and remastersys is you can backup and restore on a command line install (the ubuntu build needs *some* flavour of GUI since it uses ubiquity).The bad thing is you need some extra packages - squashfs-modules and either aufs-modules or unionfs-modules, and trying to run remastersys without them results in VERY bad things happening. You're also 'restricted' to a 4gb image.

This will however let you create a 'respin' with just your packages installed, or work as a bootable backup that will boot into your install *and* restore it to a fresh install. Its awesome and worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can do both things you are suggesting.

1. **Make an image**: Use [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to make an image of your hard drive. You can restore that image after formatting.
2. **Get a list of installed software**:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --get-selections > list.txt
   ```

   You can then reinstall them using this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install `awk '{print $1}' list.txt
   ```

   Package settings are usually in the `/etc` directory or in your `$HOME`. In general, it is a good idea to have `$HOME` in a separate partition. You do not need to reformat this partition if you reinstall so your personal settings will always be saved. For system-wide settings you can make a backup of `/etc` and copy them back to your newly formatted drive.

Bear in mind that there should be **absolutely no reason** to format your disk unless you want to install a new system.

Comment: ...I do not like your last statement. There is no need to bring *nix vs Windows vs blah elitism in here. There is nothing about Windows that forces a reinstall, just as there is nothing in Linux that says you can't mess up a system badly enough to need a reinstall. Any OS with enough freedom can be screwed up badly enough to need reinstallation - and not many of us are happy with OSes as locked down as is typical for phones/tablets.

Comment: @Bob There is indeed nothing in Windows that forces a reinstall. However, most Windows users regularly reformat their drive. See, for example, [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/chillout-room/38347-how-often-do-you-reformat.html), [here](http://www.overclock.net/t/1022315/how-often-do-you-reformat-and-reinstall-windows) and [here](http://www.techimo.com/forum/storage-related/89420-how-often-do-you-format-your-hard-drive.html). This is simply not true in the *nix world.

Comment: I can think of one... serious user error. Its sometimes faster to reinstall than to fix. There's also hardware failure, which would suck.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek sure, all I am saying is that there is no need to format unless you need to reinstall for some reason.

Comment: @terdon The days before NTFS are long, long, *long* gone. If anyone is still running Win95/98/ME, that's their fault. Of your links, the first speaks of malware. Far too much malware. Heck, I'd have to be *trying* to get that much. The second offers no reason for reformatting. The third is a decade old. I actually have not had to reformat apart from changing computers since using Win98... so I cannot say I am used to it at all. Especially in the more recent versions (>Vista) MS finally did the smart thing and restricted privileges by default.

Comment: And, really, it's always good to have a backup image even if you don't anticipate a need. I've nuked far too many systems (both Windows and Linux, though in VMs in the course of testing things - things that *seemed* safe) to not do so on my physical machines. It's all in how you use it - even in your own links, *But if I treat my \*nix installations as I treat my windows installations, I'd reinstall them just as frequently, I should think.*

Comment: @Bob I remember the days before NTFS quite clearly thank you as do many users and habits learned early on are often hard to change.In any case, the OP specifically asked about _re_formatting, something that users in the windows world (as evidenced by the posts I linked to) are used to doing quite often. I am not saying this is a good idea, it is just true that a lot of windows users believe (for reasons that may or not be correct) that reformatting every few months or years is essential. All I am saying is that this is not the case for Linux.